# Setting options on a per-type basis

Tags: biblatex, biber

In the `biblatex` documentation, under "Entry Options", it says that entry options (like `useauthor`) can be set on a per type basis.

> With Biber, this option is also settable on a per-type basis.

I want to set the same `useauthor` and `useeditor` options for all entries of a type (`@book`, `@manual`, `@online`). Is this what the quote is referring to? How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` and its optional argument. Note that *"[t]he `entrytype` argument may be a comma-separated list of values"* (manual, section 3.2.2.).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[book]{useauthor=false}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@book{K86,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The \TeX book},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]